# How to store object value into arrays in dataTable using angular 4?

Tags: angular, object, arraylist

I'm getting an object from `getView()` metho,d and the object contains a list of name. I want those names to be stored in an array. How can I do this?

```
getView() {
    return this.http.get(this.viewUrl).map(response => response.json());
}
```

**Component.ts**

```
  constructor(private userService: userservices,  private route: Router){
              this.userService.userView().subscribe(data => {this.userData = data.nameKey, alert(data)},
          err => {
            console.log('Error get values from services in Branch Component');
          });

               alert(this.userData);
               this.itemResource = new DataTableResource(this.userData);

          }
```

**DataTable.html**

```
<data-table id="persons-grid" headerTitle="Employees View"
        [items]="items" [itemCount]="itemCount" (reload)="reloadItems($event)"
        (rowClick)="rowClick($event)"
        (rowDoubleClick)="rowDoubleClick($event)" [rowTooltip]="rowTooltip">

    <data-table-column [property]="'name'" [header]="'Name'"
        [sortable]="true" [resizable]="true"> </data-table-column> <data-table-column
        [property]="'email'" [header]="'Branch Name'" [sortable]="true"
        [resizable]="true"> </data-table-column>
```

i refered from this link   https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4

Comment: response.json() contans the name?

Comment: yes but its come as list of object[object ,object]

Comment: please add the response format of the endpoint being called

Comment: @Manik added answer please check it

Comment: its come as object i checked

Comment: @manik i updated my answer. please check it with put the nameKey as your key of the name list array

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1FO5k.png @Jota.Toledo

Comment: @Manik thats as helpful as nothing

Comment: @Manik you are alredy say that the data contain list of name. So it is like a object. just try to shoe the zero th position value by usiing arrayValue[0]

Comment: I have update my code in that Im getting userInfo as an object once i get the object i want to pass the object to  DataTableResource()but DataTableResource accept only array values

Comment: @Manik i'm also updated my answer. please try with this. tyhis is just an example . change it logics accordence with your requirement

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
getView() {
return this.http.get(this.viewUrl).map(response => response.json());        
}
this.getView().subscribe((data) => {
this.arrayValue=data.nameKey;
  alert(JSON.stringify(this.userData));
})
```

Comment: I guess, This is what OP want

Comment: i try that given i got values in alert  [{"id=1,"name":"kumar"  and etc  } ]...@Ajmal sha

Comment: so u get the data from this u want to show the name value? then  change the alert code to  alert(JSON.stringify(this.userData[0].name))

Comment: i getting the values in alert but i want to pass array value to DataTableResource pls see above i have update